# How do I fix this element overlapping issue when I zoom in IE7?

Tags: html, css

When I zoom in in IE7, the element with position relative gets overlapped..How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML5</title>


<style type="text/css" media="all">
.wrapper{width:500px;height:1000px;border:1px red solid;}

.block1{border:1px red solid;width:100px ;height:100px;position:relative;}

.block2{border:1px red solid;width:100px ;height:100px;}

.block3{border:1px red solid;width:100px ;height:100px;}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="block1">A</div>

<div class="block2">B</div>

<div class="block3">C</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tries adding zoom:1 to .block1 also but it didn't work

Comment: How to fix the page or how to fix IE?

Answer (score 0):

```
.block1 {
    zoom: 1 ;
}
```

Try something like this,  Hope this helps.